# Test the hyperlinks of a pdf document

Tags: hyperref, pdf, urls, links

Is there any way to test the hyperlinks of a `pdf` file ?
Suppose I have a `pdf` file containing a large number of hyperlinks, can I test automatically the response I will have when following those links (`200` = ok, `404` = not found, etc.).

I know such tools exists for webpages (as softwares, like [KLinkStatus](https://www.kde.org/applications/development/klinkstatus), or as webservices, like [the checklink of the W3C](http://validator.w3.org/checklink)) but is there any equivalent for `pdf`?
As I guess there is no such thing, is there any nice equivalent for `tex` files? I guess this can be done with some scripts and regexp magic, but I was wondering if there was any existing solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/test-404/}{This will give a 404}

\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}{This will give a 200}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I googled "testing pdf hyperlinks" and found several intersting sites, like http://www.axmag.com/manual/PC/Activate_Links.htm

Comment: This is useless: this website propose to "convert" your PDF files (into what?) and then to "click on the links to see if they are activated." So it is just a useless conversion to end up clicking on every link, like I could do on a pdf file.

Comment: I guess another option would be to use [latex2html](http://www.latex2html.org/) to produce an `html` document that could be easily tested, but I'm sure something more natural exists…

Comment: Wouldn't [su] be a better place for asking this? It's not really related to TeX and friends.

Comment: As noted, this is off-topic for TeX-sx as there is no need here for TeX to be involved (one could as the same question about any PDF). I've refunded the bounty: it's too late to migrate, so I suggest asking a repeat question on Super User (perhaps miss out the TeX code entirely).

Comment: This question was not totally off-topic to me because the hyperlinks can be tested either in the pdf, either in the source code. So answers from both worlds were suitable, and I could not imagine a community that would grasp so quickly what were my needs and tools.

Comment: I don't understand how this is off-topic, either. I could easily imagine an answer consisting of (hypothetically) an option to `hyperref` that produces a `.txt` file with URLs in them and them a quick script (like in the accepted answer) to check the status codes. For a similar style of question/answer, consider the minted questions about using custom lexers and highlighting schemes (which tend to show Python code).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install curl (assuming you use apt-get to install packages) :

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

and do the following for pdf files:

```
cat document.pdf | grep -ao '[a-zA-Z]\+://[a-zA-Z.-]*[^)]\+' | while read LINE; do curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code}' "$LINE";    echo " $LINE";  done
```

and do the following for tex files :

```
cat myfile.tex | grep -o '{[a-zA-Z]\+://[a-zA-Z.-]*[^}]\+}' | sed s/{// | sed s/}// | while read LINE; do curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code}' "$LINE" echo " $LINE" done
```

Copy paste the following to your command line for an immediate test:

```
echo "\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/test-404/}{This will give a 404}

\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}{This will give a 200}

\end{document}" | grep -o '{[a-zA-Z]\+://[a-zA-Z.-]*[^}]\+}' | sed s/{// | sed s/}// | while read LINE; do
   curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code}' "$LINE"
   echo " $LINE"
 done
```

Refer to the following for details:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611973/how-to-grep-for-a-url-in-a-file
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136022/script-to-get-the-http-status-code-of-a-list-of-urls

Comment: @Joseph Wright ... I think it's unfair that the bounty got refunded ;-)

Comment: @Clément at least a tip would be nice ;-)

Comment: There is no way I can do that. And I am sorry that the bounty has been refused, but cannot do anything to change that.

Comment: Just upvote my solution ;-)

Comment: I already did, of course!

Comment: This solution did not work with one of my particular pdf, so I coupled it with [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43810795/2657549) and obtained `pdftk main.pdf cat output out.pdf uncompress; strings out.pdf | grep -i http | grep -ao '[a-zA-Z]\+://[a-zA-Z.-]*[^)]\+' | while read LINE; do curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code}' "$LINE";    echo " $LINE";  done` that worked ok.

Answer (score 3):

If you are open to using Python this may suffice.

I use python with the pyPdf and urllib2 packages. The logic goes like this: Open a pdf with pyPdf.PdfFileReader and loop through it. In the function below, `pdf` is the open pdf file object.

```
def get_urls(pdf):
    badurls = list()
    links = list()
    url_checker = URLChecker() # a helper function to test the URL (urllib2)
    for pg in range(pdf.getNumPages()):
        page = pdf.getPage(pg)
        obj = page.getObject()

        for a in obj.get('/Annots', []):
            u = a.getObject()
            lnk = u['/A'].get('/D')
            url = u['/A'].get('/URI')
            if lnk:
                links.append(lnk)
            if url:
                urls.append(url)
                result, reason = url_checker.check(url)
                if not result:
                    badurls.append({'url':url, 'reason': '%r' % reason})

    anchors = pdf.getNamedDestinations().keys()
    badlinks = [x for x in links if x not in anchors]
    return urls, badurls, badlinks
```

The `url_checker` opens the url and if there is an error, it returns `(False, error_string)`. Otherwise it returns `(True, None)`

So at the end of the process, you have a a list of urls in the pdf, any bad urls that could not be opened (containing the reason), a list of links in the PDF, and a the subset of those links that do not have target anchors.

I've omitted the logic for the url_checker, but it is pretty simple. There are multiple ways to do that part--you could also use the `requests` package instead of `urllib2`.

Comment: "Open a pdf with pyPdf.PdfFileReader and loop through it." [I know some of these words](http://gfycat.com/UnitedImpureAlaskajingle). Please could you be more precise ?

Comment: @Clément, yes it is actually in the code block--see the two for loops? The first (outer loop) loops through the pages in the document, the second (inner loop) loops through the annotations on each given page. Anything on a page that responds to the user is an Annotation. If you write a function to check the url, and pass the function above an open PDF file (using pyPdf lib), the code above will work as-is. If you need more help, please be specific on what is giving you problems. I think this answer won't help you much if you don't already know python.

Comment: As you guessed, for someone who does already know python, this comment is of little help. Could you start from the beginning, please: "save  this as a file, open a terminal, etc." ?

Answer (score 2):

A simple C++ program using Qt4 and Poppler would do the trick. I quickly sketched it up and tested it on some PDFs. I think one could tweak it a lot to make it more robust against weird links like mailto: -protocol and other ports. And of course Output formatting can be better, if you need to parse it afterwards, but it does the trick

```
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QList>
#include <poppler-qt4.h>
#include <QDebug>

  using namespace Poppler;

  QString urlGetStatus(const QUrl &url) {
    QString status;
    QTcpSocket socket;
    socket.connectToHost(url.host(), 80);
    if (socket.waitForConnected()) {
        socket.write("HEAD " + url.path().toUtf8() + " HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                     "Host: " + url.host().toUtf8() + "\r\n"
                     "\r\n");
        if (socket.waitForReadyRead()) {
                QByteArray bytes = socket.readAll();
                status = QString(bytes).mid(9, 3);
        }
    }
    return status;
  }

  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc < 2) {
        return 1;
    }
    QString path = QString(argv[1]);
    Document *doc = Document::load(path);
    if(doc == NULL)
        return 1;
    QList<QUrl> urlList;
    for(int i = 0;i < doc->numPages(); i++) {        
        Page *p = doc->page(i);
        foreach(Link *li,p->links()) {
            if(li->linkType() == Link::Browse) {
                LinkBrowse *link = static_cast<LinkBrowse*>(li);
                urlList.append(QUrl(link->url()));
            }
        }
    }
    foreach(QUrl url, urlList) {
        QString stat = urlGetStatus(url);
        if(stat == "200") {
            qDebug() << url.toString() << "returned status 200";
        } else {
            qDebug() << url.toString() << " maybe not reachable status" << stat;
        }
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

As I am a cmake friend I used this CMakeLists.txt to compile:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(qlinkextract)
set (CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")

find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED QtCore QtNetwork)
include(${QT_USE_FILE})

find_package(Poppler REQUIRED)
include_directories(${POPPLER_QT_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(qlinkextract main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(qlinkextract ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${POPPLER_QT_LIBRARIES})
```

You will need Qt4 development packages and Poppler-Qt4 development packages. If
you don't have a FindPoppler.cmake in your CMakeModules directories, go and grab one online.

To compile it make sure in the project directory qlinkextract is (needs to be exactly spelled like the followng)

- CMakeLists.txt (see above)
- main.cpp  (see above)
- cmake/Modules/FindPoppler.cmake (download from somewhere)
- build/ (folder is optional)

on a console go to the build folder and type

```
cmake ..
make
```

if something is missing install the missing packages

Some example output:

```
"http://www.igi-global.com/chapter/ontology-based-multimedia-indexing/42895?camid=4v1" returned status 200 
"http://www.igi-global.com/chapter/ontology-based-multimedia-indexing/42895?camid=4v1" returned status 200 
"http://www.igi-global.com/e-resources/library-recommendation/?id=1" returned status 200 
"http://www.igi-global.com/chapter/towards-low-cost-energy-monitoring/112719?camid=4v1a" returned status 200 
"http://www.igi-global.com/article/algebraic-properties-of-rough-set-on-two-universal-sets-based-on-multigranulation/116046?camid=4v1a" returned status 200 
"http://www.igi-global.com/article/algebraic-properties-of-rough-set-on-two-universal-sets-based-on-multigranulation/116046?camid=4v1a" returned status 200 
"http://www.igi-global.com/article/fuzzy-decision-support-system-for-coronary-artery-disease-diagnosis-based-on-rough-set-theory/111313?camid=4v1a" returned status 200 
"http://www.igi-global.com/article/fuzzy-decision-support-system-for-coronary-artery-disease-diagnosis-based-on-rough-set-theory/111313?camid=4v1a" returned status 200 
"http://www.igi-global.com/chapter/optimization-model-identification-temperature-intelligent/74536?camid=4v1a" returned status 200 
"http://www.igi-global.com/chapter/optimization-model-identification-temperature-intelligent/74536?camid=4v1a" returned status 200
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your post provides some answer to a probably off-topic question. It has nothing to do with (La)TeX itself.

Comment: Yes I agree. But it got asked here, so I thought I could help anyway. WIll it be moved to somewhere else?

Comment: SeDaV: It might be migrated to Super User, but I did not flag your post as off-topic, since I did not want to get it deleted. The question and all answers should be migrated as a bundle, of course. I think this will happen after the bounty period has ended.

Comment: I think, it's a helpful post anyway