# How to disable hyperlinks pointing to none existing labels

Tags: beamer, pdftex, hyperref

I'm making a presentation with `beamer` and I would like to make links (with `\hyperlink`) to some parts (with `\label`) by using the `hyperref` package.

For pratical reason, I have splitted my presentation into several text files called with `\input`. When I build my `pdf` without a specific section, the links which points to the missing labels in the section are pointing to the first page of the presentation (which is incorrect).

**Is it possible to disable the broken links (not pointing to anything) into a LaTeX document ?**

**Is there a command to test if a `\label` is present inside a document ?**

---

Here is a basic example :

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,utf8]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame 1}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame 2}
\label{label1}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame 3}
\hyperlink{label1}{link to label1}\par         % This link is OK.
\hyperlink{label2}{link to missing label2}\par % This link should be disabled
\ref{label1}\par                               % This ref is OK
\ref{label2}                                   % This ref should be disabled
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide an example document that has this setup

Comment: Are the files independent with their own documentclass etc. or are they included in a larger document and just comments out?

Comment: The text files don't have any LaTeX header. They are just read with the `\input` command.

Comment: @JeanJouX: Are the explicit `\hyperlink` statements really necessary? You're labelling them already, isn't a `\ref` sufficient?

Comment: `\ref` could be OK but It doesn't change the problem. The ref associated to a missing label point to the page 1.

Comment: Similar question, but with `href` (i.e., external links): http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/204343/34551

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to exploit `\IfRefUndefinedExpandable` from `refcount` package (loaded by `hyperref` loaded, so no extra loading is needed).

See the wrapper commands `\hyperrefcheck` and `\checkref` for this.

Warning: You will miss other non-existing references as well.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,utf8]{beamer}





\newcommand{\hyperlinkcheck}[2]{%
  \IfRefUndefinedExpandable{#1}{%
    % Do nothing
  }{%
    \hyperlink{#1}{#2}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\checkref}[1]{%
  \IfRefUndefinedExpandable{#1}{%
    % Do Nothing
  }{%
    \ref{#1}%
  }%
}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame 1}
\end{frame}



\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame 2}
\label{label1}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame 3}
  \hyperlinkcheck{label1}{link to label1}
         % This link is OK.
  \hyperlinkcheck{label2}{link to missing label2} % This link should be disabled

  \checkref{label1}                               % This ref is OK

  \checkref{label2}                               % This ref should be disabled
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```